# How to control the usage of APIs by consumers during a given period (throttle) in Azure function app Http trigger without using Azure API Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How to control the usage of APIs by consumers during a given period in Azure function app Http trigger. Simply how to set a requests throttle when exceed the request limit, and please let me know a solution without using azure API Gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only control you have over host creation in Azure Functions an obscure application setting: `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT`. This implies that you can control the number of hosts that are generated, though Microsoft claim that “it’s not completely foolproof” and “is not fully supported”.

From my own experience **it only throttles host creation effectively if you set the value to something pretty low**, i.e. less than 50. At larger values then its impact is pretty limited. It’s been implied that this feature will be will be worked on in the future, but the corresponding issue has been open in GitHub with [no update since July 2017](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1207).

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://www.ben-morris.com/managing-serverless-scaling-with-azure-functions-by-throttling-throughput/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `initialVisibilityDelay` property of the `CloudQueue.AddMessage` function as outlined in this [blog post](https://www.vrdmn.com/2018/04/azure-functions-add-message-to-queue.html).

This will throttle the message to prevent the 429 error if implemented correctly using the leaky bucket algorithm or equivalent.